# Android ListView::setItemChecked doesn't work

Tags: android, listview

I tried to show simple checked list and I need some items to be checked.

Here is my code

`ArrayAdapter<Task> taskAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Task>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, tasksList);
        this.getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        this.getListView().setItemChecked(2, true);
        setListAdapter(taskAdapter);`

```
<ListView
   android:id="@android:id/list"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

And still it doesn't work.
Implementation of Checkable interface didn't help.

What's the trick of this ListView?

Comment: Try to set the adapter before `setItemChecked()`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to set the adapter before setting the item as checkable.

```
ArrayAdapter<Task> taskAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Task>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, tasksList);
setListAdapter(taskAdapter);        
this.getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE); 
this.getListView().setItemChecked(2, true);
```

The adapter contains the data stored in the listview so Item 2 does not exist in the listview until the adapter is set.