# why the boxes doesn't check? android

Tags: android, checkbox

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

ArrayAdapter<String> arr;
ListView list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[] st = {"aa","bb","cc"};
    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    arr = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, st);
    list.setAdapter(arr);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    list.setItemChecked(arg2, true);
}
```

}

It's really simple code, and still the boxes do not check. This means I don't understand something.

Comment: take look on this thread 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989662/android-listviewsetitemchecked-doesnt-work

Comment: I did... didnt understand it too much

Comment: what's the part that obvious for you ?

Comment: Well I am looking to check it in my Item click listener... and it dosent talk about it in the thread you just wrote

Comment: and I set the adapter before I tried to check...
look at the functions...

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the problem to all my questions! (and there were quit a few of them)

and the problem was when I did the xml

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/stationsList1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

  **android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"**
```

>

forgot that...